# powershell stop service remotely

Tags: powershell

I have to stop SQLSERVER service on multiple servers and in the same time check state to be sure they are stopped.
Now my code looks like this:

```
$vmlist = Get-Content C:\xx.txt
foreach($VM in $VMlist)
{
    Get-Service -ComputerName $VM | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.name -match “MSSQLSERVER”} | ForEach-Object {$_.stop()}
    Start-Sleep 5
    Get-Service -ComputerName $VM | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like “MSSQLSERVER“} | Select-Object -Property machineName,name,Displayname,status
}
```

The WAIT step is  really creepy but had no idea how to do it other way
Could you suggest a way i could rewrite it in order to stop the service, wait till it is stopped and then return state?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Stop` method from the [`ServiceController`class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) there is another method called `WaitForStatus`. The 2 parameter overload is safer because you can specific a timeout so that your script doesn't hang if the service never stops.

```
$vmlist = Get-Content C:\xx.txt
foreach($VM in $VMlist) {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $VM |
    ? { $_.Name -match “MSSQLSERVER” } | % {
        $_.Stop()
        $_.WaitForStatus('Stopped','00:00:05')
    } 
    Get-Service -ComputerName $VM |
    ? { $_.Name -like “MSSQLSERVER“ } | 
    Select machineName, name, Displayname, status 
}
```